# How to fix 'ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken' error in Shopify App with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, shopify-app

I'm running a Shopify app in development mode with Rails 5.2 hosted on a remote ngrok server.
When I try to Post a record, I get the 'ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken' error from Rails.
When I disable CSRF tokens then the Shopify app doesn't work and shows an error, so I don't want to disable CSRF protection,
but don't know how to bypass this error without doing so.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
Rails 5 ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error and ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

Referencing the above two questions I added the following code to my application_controller.rb

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
protect_from_forgery prepend: true, with: :exception
```

However, the errors persist.

**Form which results in errors after being submitted**

```
<form action="/create_shipment" method="post">
    <%= token_tag %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="e.g. johnsmith">
        
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Secret Key</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="key" placeholder="e.g. 34ssdfkje3483jkdj83...">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'home#index'
  post '/create_shipment', :to => 'add_user#add_shipment_data'
  get '/products', :to => 'products#index'
  
  mount ShopifyApp::Engine, at: '/'
end
```

**add_user_ontroller.rb**

```
class AddUserController < ApplicationController
  def add_shipment_data
    @user = AddUser.new
    @user.username = params[:username]
    @user.secret_key = params[:key]
    @user.save
  end
end
```

**shopify_app.rb**

```
ShopifyApp.configure do |config|
  config.application_name = "Shipment Method"
  config.old_secret = ""
  config.scope = "write_products, read_products, read_customers, read_orders, write_orders" # Consult this page for more scope options:
                                  # https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth/scopes
  config.embedded_app = true
  config.after_authenticate_job = false
  config.api_version = "2021-01"
  config.shop_session_repository = 'Shop'
  config.allow_jwt_authentication = true
  config.allow_cookie_authentication = false

  config.api_key = ENV.fetch('SHOPIFY_API_KEY', SHOPIFY_API_KEY).presence
  config.secret = ENV.fetch('SHOPIFY_API_SECRET', SHOPIFY_API_SECRET).presence
  if defined? Rails::Server
    raise('Missing SHOPIFY_API_KEY. See https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app#api-keys') unless config.api_key
    raise('Missing SHOPIFY_API_SECRET. See https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app#api-keys') unless config.secret
  end
end
```

**[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ljFa.png)**

Answer (score 0):

I spent many hours trying to figure out why I got CSRF errors with ngrok.  Turns out that most (all?) browsers have a list of domains they won't store cookies that can be accessed by subdomains, ngrok.io is in this list.
Firefox just tells you the domain is invalid and chrome tells you the domain is not valid for the host, not the true reason.

My first solution was to do
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, ..., tld_length: 3

Then I decided on this

```
module ActionDispatch                                                                             
  class Cookies
    class CookieJar                                                                               
      alias handle_options_orig handle_options                                                    
      def handle_options(options)
        if request.host  =~ /ngrok.io/                                                            
          options[:tld_length] = 3                                                                
        end
        handle_options_orig(options)                                                              
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The browser will store cookies for X.ngrok.io, but not .ngrok.io which seems to be the default.

This was for Rails 5